# run python script with pyspark settings

Tags: python, pyspark

I have Spark configuration in spark-defaults.conf, xml files: core-site.xml, hive-site.xml, and I exported environment variables. When I run pyspark console:

```
$ pyspark --master yarn
```

and then:

```
>>> sqlContext.sql("show tables").show()
```

everything is correct, but when I use pure python interpreter I cannot see my tables.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("show tables").show()
```

How can I make python see all config files?

Comment: What is the result/exception you get when run the code in the interpreter?

Comment: If I run it in python I get empty result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that when you run the PySpark Shell, Spark is instantiated with support for Hive i.e `HiveContext`, which defaults to `SQLContext`.

But while running a Python Program or the Python Interpreter, as in your case, the SQLContext does not come with Hive support.

To fix this

```
sqlCtx = HiveContext(sc)
sqlCtx.sql("show tables").show()
```

Comment: I tried to use some code of pyspark scipt and it also works but your solution is much simpler.